# kineticjs - drag using two touches iOS & android

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

Using KineticJS - Is there way to implement drag on image functionality using two touch on iOS or Android OS.
When an object is made draggable, the default is one touch drag. How to change it to two touch drag.

I am trying to implement two touch to drag an image and use one touch for a free draw like canvas pen drawing.

Comment: Using below example, how can I modify it to drag using two touches? http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-an-image-tutorial/

Comment: you need to grab the event object from the browser rather than from kineticJS. Then you can get touch[0] and touch[1] as separate touch events. Using that, you can set draggable on touch[0] and drag with touch[1]. See this: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-multi-touch-scale-shape-with-kineticjs/

Answer (score 0):

Currently (v5.1.0) KineticJS has no support of dragging multiple objects at same time.

But you may use this plugin: https://github.com/atomictag/Kinetic.MultiTouch